# USB hub not working on Ubuntu 20 but working on Windows

Tags: usb

My USB hub (connecting via USB-C) is refusing to work on Ubuntu 20.

I can plug it in to Windows and it works there so something with my Ubuntu 20 set up.

If it helps `lsusb` does not show it appear either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. Do you mean 20,10 or 20,04?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: FYI:  I have USB hubs that don't show up in `lsusb`; but they work just fine regardless (depending on the alert level, they did generate a number of warnings if the level was set high, but at lower levels I get nothing... works fine though)

Comment: Is anything plugged into the hub?